# Paginating hashes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, will-paginate

I am using the will_paginate gem to paginate my rails application. I am building a tree view structure (basically a hash structure) with one of my collections. It goes like this:

```
Root
 ╰─╴Suite
     ╰─╴TestCase
         ╰─╴Ic
```

I want to paginate this. I tried the following code but it throws an error saying `undefined method 'paginate' for #<Hash:0xb707f190>`.

Controller code:

```
def index
  @ics = Ic.search(
           params[ :root_name ],  params[ :suite_name ],
           params[ :case_name ],  params[ :name ],
           'f'
         )

  @ics_temp = Ic.make_tree( @ics ).paginate :per_page => 100,
                                            :page     => params[ :all_ics ]
end
```

View code:

```
- form_tag "/ics/mass_action", :method => :post, :multipart => true do

  <div id="update_ics_table">
  = render "listing",
      :show_check_boxes => show_check_boxes,
      :root_name        => params[:root_name],
      :suite_name       => params[:suite_name],
      :case_name        => params[:case_name],
      :name             => params[:name],
      :ic_filter        => 1
  </div>

  = will_paginate @ics_temp, :param_name => :all_ics
```

Also please help me with how to ajaxify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paginate a `Hash`, you'll have to add `paginate` method to Class `Hash`.
Here is a link, that shows you how to do so with an Array.

- [Will paginate and Arrays](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=13766)

Just do as it says, but change the function as per Hash.

Comment: @ramya: If you have found solution to your problem, post it here in an answer, so that others can use it too :).